# SQL: create another column that calculates ratio

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

So I have a table that looks like the following:

| car owner | non car owner | have dog | num ppl |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 60 |  |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 80 |  |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 90 |  |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 98 |  |

I am trying to add another column to find the ratios. For example, the total number of car owners is 110. If I want to find the ratio of people who own car and have dog, then I have to divide 60/110 for the first row. Also, the total number of non car owners is 98. Therefore, if I want to find that ration, I need to divide 80 by 98 for the second row and so on.
So far, I have tried the following code:

```
with a as (
    select
        id,
        case when car_owner = 1 then 1 else 0 end car_owner,
        case when non_car_owner = 1 then 1 else 0 end as non_car_owner = 1 
    from `xyz_table` 
),
b as (select
    car_owner,
    non_car_owner,
    case when have_dog = 1 then 1 else 0 end have_dog,
    count(distinct id) num_ppl
from `xyz_table`
join a using (id)
group by 1,2,3
order by 4 desc
)
select *, num_ppl/(select (case when dog_owner = 1 then 110 else 0 end) as ratio
                         from a)
from b
```

Unfortunately , it throws the following error:

```
Scalar subquery produced more than one element
```

Any help would be appreciated.

PS. I am running this code on google bigquery.

Comment: Where does the `80` come from?

Comment: show expected output?

Answer (score 0):

> If I want to find the ratio of people who own car and have dog,

You can use `avg()`:

```
select avg(car_owner * have_dog)
from t;
```